# Deadlocks sin transacciones en MySQL (MariaDB)

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

estoy teniendo un problema muy extraño. Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con PHP 7.1.17 y MariaDB 5.5.56. Las tablas utilizan el motor InnoDB.

La dinámica es la siguiente. Un usuario va a realizar un pedido con un nº X de artículos. Cuando realizan dicho pedido, se procesan los datos (crear factura, modificar stocks, etc...) y es en éste momento, cuando se producen, de manera desconocida, errores a la hora de realizar UPDATE.

Haciendo un seguimiento durante varios días, no he alcanzado a encontrar un patrón de error (de un bloque con el mismo id de pedido, algunas veces es al primero, otras al tercero, etc...). Sin embargo, generé un log en el que, entre otros datos, almacenaba el error que devolvía MariaDB y me indica:

```
Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

Revisando la documentación, nos evidencia que esto es una cuestión de un interbloqueo entre transacciones. Sin embargo, se da la paradoja de que no hay transacciones en todo éste desarrollo. De hecho, éste UPDATE se encuentra en un foreach por cada uno de los artículos antes mencionados.

Por motivos que no vienen al caso, en mi servidor no puedo hacer SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS, sin embargo, puedo obtener estos datos revisando en el estado actual del servidor:

```
Innodb row lock time             90.1 k
Innodb row lock time avg            154 
Innodb row lock time max          4.8 k 
Innodb row lock waits               584
Innodb deadlocks                      0
```

La query que la inmensa mayoría de veces falla es la misma:

```
UPDATE datos_pedido SET entregado='1',unidades='2',almacen='2',fin_de_garantia='2020-5-14 17:34:42' WHERE pedido='355860' AND producto='46880'
```

Todos los campos son índices, pero no están relacionados con otras tablas. En el desarrollo, el AUTOCOMMIT está establecido a True.

¿Que puede estar sucediendo? Parece un error muy evidente y sin embargo, no logro encontrar información de casos similares (Deadlock sin utilizar propiamente dichas transacciones). ¿Que mas datos necesitaría recabar para poder solucionarlo?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Puedes añadir la salida del SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS?

Comment: Como mencionaba en el caso, no tengo acceso, no puedo añadir esa salida.

Comment: Sin eso es complicado obtener una respuesta con las consultas problemáticas, habla con el administrador para que te pase dicha información, espero que sea posible.